# How to get Team City to only trigger a build on a Github pull request if it contains changes in a specific folder

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a TeamCity configuration to monitor Github pull requests, such that it will pick up any pull requests from Github and then triggers a build.

Now, I only want it to trigger a bulid for the pull requests that contains changes in a specific folder.

Let's say my repo root folder is c:\myProject, the specific folder is c:\myProject\HelloWorld.  My aim is to get TeamCity to only trigger a build if the pull request contains changes to the files in HelloWorld folder.

Any thoughts on how to configure it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your VCS Trigger, you can define a [trigger rule](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules) with an Ant-like wildcard, in this case +:HelloWorld/** (the exact file path syntax may be incorrect in this example).

Comment: Make sure the path you specify is correct, as it is case sensitive!

Comment: In my experience this approach doesn't work. The problem seems to be that TeamCity compares the PR branch with the beginning of time when it is looking for diffs, so it will always find diffs in every directory that exists in your PR.